# Simpler way to check if string start with a digit in Rust?

Tags: string, rust

What I am currently using is this

```
fn main() {
    let a = "abc123";
    let b = "1a2b3c";

    println!("{}", a[0..1].chars().all(char::is_numeric));
    println!("{}", b[0..1].chars().all(char::is_numeric));
}
```

Are there a more idiomatic and/or simpler way to do this?

Note: The string is guaranteed to be non empty and made of ASCII characters.

Comment: This example panics if the string is non-ASCII or empty; is that the desired behavior?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are sure that it is non-empty and made out of ascii, you can operate directly on bytes (`u8`):

```
a.as_bytes()[0].is_ascii_digit()
```

or

```
(b'0'..=b'9').contains(&a.as_bytes()[0])
```

More general setting (and, *in my opinion*, more idiomatic):

```
a.chars().next().unwrap().is_numeric()
```

The reason all this looks a bit unwieldy is that there may be some things going wrong (that are easily overlooked in other languages):

- string might be empty => leads us into `Option`/`unwrap`-land
- strings in rust are UTF-8 (which basically complicates random-accessing into string; note that rust does *not only* consider 0-9 as numeric, as shown [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.is_numeric))

Comment: `a.chars().next().map(char::is_numeric).unwrap_or(false)` could make sense

Comment: I'd expect if you're testing whether the *first character* of a string is numeric or not, it's as some kind of precursor to parsing it -- in which case `is_digit(10)` (or even `is_ascii_digit()`) is probably more correct than `is_numeric()`. You might not want your lexer to categorize `"¾"` as "numeric" and then hand it to a parser that's expecting a digit.

Comment: @trentcl Interesting … I was going to recommend that `is_numeric()` should be used because you don't just want `[0-9]` to be accepted. There are so many other numeric characters in Unicode like ０１２３４５６７８９． `is_digit(10)` might be the best choice then. I definitely recommend not using `is_ascii_digit()`.

Comment: @Matthias Yeah, `is_digit(10)` is what I would use, but `is_ascii_digit` technically does the same thing. Rust does not have any standard library functions that can turn non-ASCII numeric characters into their numeric values like `'３'` into `3`, so if your parser accepts some of those, you probably want to write your own `is_digit` code too.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from your original solution and `parse`:

```
fn main() {
    let a = "abc123";
    let b = "1a2b3c";
    
    println!("{:?}", a[0..1].parse::<u8>().is_ok());  // false
    println!("{:?}", b[0..1].parse::<u8>().is_ok());  // true
}
```

If the first character is guaranteed to be ASCII and the string is not empty.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=be35e48bdfceb78498a1f0b054af7b00)